# Why // is needed instead of /

Tags: xpath, scrapy

consider the following HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>      
  <title>Example website</title>
</head>
 <body>    
  <div>
  <table id='tableid'>
   <tr>
    <td>
        <a href="/blabla" title="Blabla1">Blabla1</a>
        <a href="/blabla" title="Blabla1">Blabla2</a>
        <a href="/blabla" title="Blabla1">Blabla3</a>
        <a href="/blabla" title="Blabla1">Blabla4</a>
    </td>
        <td>col2</td>
        <td>col3</td>
        <td>col4</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

If I want to get all the links why do I have to use:

```
//table[@id="tableid"]//a/@href
```

instead if using a single / after the table? I'm alredy on the table node at that point (it should become my 'root') so / should be enough...

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A single `/` after `table[@id="tableid"]` would work if you only wanted immediate children of `table`.  To get any descendent `a` of `table[@id="tableid"]`, you need `//a`.

`//` is short for `/descendant-or-self::node()/`

The descendant-or-self axis contains the context node and the descendants of the context node.  Since you're establishing the context node as `table[@id="tableid"]`, you won't get any `a` elements other than those that are descendants of `table[@id="tableid"]`.

Answer (score 3):

```
//table[@id="tableid"]
```

Will find all `<table>` elements with an `id` equal to `tableid`.

```
//a/@href
```

Added after this will find all `<a>` elements within the `<table>` element, on any position (child, grandchild ...)

If you are sure all the `<a>` elements you need are below the first `<td>` (table --> tr --> td) you can skip the second `//` and do:

```
//table[@id="tableid"]/tr[1]/td[1]/a/@href
```

The `/tr[1]/td[1]` will go directly to the `<a>` elements.